# how to compare two files on names and remove the common name and corresponding value from first file

Tags: batch-file

I have two .properties files as follows

```
first.properties                    second.properties
-----------------                   ---------------------
firstname=firstvalue                fourthname=100100
secondname=secondvalue              sixthname=200200
thirdname=thirdvalue                nineththname=ninethvalue
fourthname=fourthvalue              tenthname=tenthvalue
fifthname=fifthvalue
sixthname=sixthvalue
seventhname=seventhvalue
```

i want to compare two files with the names and need to remove common name and corresponding value from first.properties. The output file should be as

```
third.properties.
------------------ 
firstname=firstvalue                
secondname=secondvalue              
thirdname=thirdvalue            
fifthname=fifthvalue
seventhname=seventhvalue
```

i used the following code,but it is giving Cartesian product scenario.can you please help me out to achieve the above.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%E in (first.properties) do (
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G in (second.properties) do (
    if "%%E" NEQ "%%G" echo %%E=%%F>>!HOME!\Properties\third.properties
    )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off
(for /f "delims==" %%i in (second.properties) do echo(%%i.*)>temp.properties
findstr /rvg:temp.properties first.properties>third.properties
del temp.properties
```

..output in `third.properties` is:

```
firstname=firstvalue
secondname=secondvalue
thirdname=thirdvalue
fifthname=fifthvalue
seventhname=seventhvalue
```

at the request of the OP I add a (much slower) solution without a temp file:

```
@echo off
(for /f "tokens=1,2delims==" %%i in (first.properties) do findstr /r "%%i.*" second.properties >nul||echo(%%i=%%j)>third.properties
type third.properties
```

Comment: Thanks Endoro,Its working good.Can we do the same thing without writing to the temp file.

Comment: The `findstr /g` option does only work with files. Generally, it is possible but coding is much more time consuming and the solution will be much slower. I can look into, but unfortunately this will take time.

Comment: @Thiru - added solution without temp file.

Answer (score 0):

The Batch file below does not create temporary files nor use external commands (like findstr.exe), so it run faster.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create list of names in second file
set "secondNames=/"
for /F "delims==" %%a in (second.properties) do set "secondNames=!secondNames!%%a/"

rem Copy properties of first file that does not appear in second one
(for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in (first.properties) do (
   if "!secondNames:/%%a/=!" equ "%secondNames%" (
      echo %%a=%%b
   )
)) > third.properties
```

I used a slash to delimit property names. If this character may appear in the names, just select a different one in the program.

Previous solution eliminate any exclamation mark from the files; this detail may be fixed, if needed.